# Faster type-safe version of apply (i.e. multivariate vapply)

Tags: r, apply, lapply

One of the main performance bottlenecks in `jsonlite` turns out to be apply, so I was wondering if there are more efficient alternatives to apply functions on the rows or columns of a matrix.

For one dimensional structures, `vapply` is often significantly faster than `lapply` or `sapply` because it can allocate output space at the beginning, rather than trying to simplify the output lists at the very end:

```
> x <- runif(5e6)
> system.time(y1 <- sapply(x, sqrt))
   user  system elapsed 
  7.231   0.142   7.370 
> system.time(y2 <- vapply(x, sqrt, numeric(1)))
   user  system elapsed 
  1.314   0.095   1.410
```

However `vapply` does not work for matrices structures. Is there an analogous function for the `apply` family? Currently the output type of `apply` depends on `FUN`, for example:

```
#returns vector
apply(volcano, 1, mean)

#returns matrix
apply(volcano, 1, fivenum)

#returns list
apply(volcano, 1, function(x){list(mean=mean(x), sd=sd(x))})
```

This [script](https://gist.github.com/jeroenooms/6801d7c828bcc682b754) has a simple example of `apply` in action.

Comment: See `?colSums` for some handy functions that have been optimized for your pleasure.

Comment: Do you have some examples of specific bottlenecks?

Comment: @hadley: https://gist.github.com/jeroenooms/6801d7c828bcc682b754

Comment: Presumably you'd also like to avoid the `as.matrix()` if the input is a data frame

Comment: The input matrix is already character matrix (each value a json element). Apply is used to create the json records: https://github.com/jeroenooms/jsonlite/blob/master/R/asJSON.data.frame.R#L91-L93

Comment: I suspect you'd be better off optimising that function as a whole. Also seems like a `json_vector` generic would simplify a lot of the code. And how wedded to S4 are you?

Comment: I think what you mean by `json_vector` has been implemented as `asJSON(x, collapse=FALSE)`. I'm not married (or even engaged) to S4, but that might get a little OT.